# Sys.set_signal interrupts input_line on the main thread, but not in children threads

Tags: multithreading, signals, ocaml

What is the proper way to write an interruptible reader thread in OCaml?  Concretely, the following single-threaded program works (that is, <kbd>Ctrl-C Ctrl-C</kbd> interrupts it immediately):

```
exception SigInt

let _ =
  Sys.set_signal Sys.sigint (Sys.Signal_handle (fun _ -> raise SigInt));
  try output_string stdout (input_line stdin);
  with SigInt -> print_endline "SINGLE_SIGINT"
```

The following program, on the other hand, cannot be interrupted with C-c C-c:

```
let _ =
  Sys.set_signal Sys.sigint (Sys.Signal_handle (fun _ -> raise SigInt));
  let go () =
    try output_string stdout (input_line stdin);
    with SigInt -> print_endline "CHILD_SIGINT" in
  try Thread.join (Thread.create go ());
  with SigInt -> print_endline "PARENT_SIGINT"
```

**What's a cross-platform way to implement an interruptible reader thread in OCaml?**.  That is, what changes do I need to make to the multithreaded program above to make it interruptible?

I've explored multiple hypotheses to understand why the multi-threaded example above was not working, but none made sense full to me:

- Maybe input_line isn't interruptible? But the the single-threaded example above would not work.
- Maybe `Thread.join` is blocking the signal for the whole process?  But in that case the following example would not be interruptible either:

  ```
  let _ =
    Sys.set_signal Sys.sigint (Sys.Signal_handle (fun _ -> raise SigInt));
    let rec alloc acc =
      alloc (1::acc) in
    let go () =
      try alloc []
      with SigInt -> print_endline "CHILD_SIGINT" in
    try Thread.join (Thread.create go ());
    with SigInt -> print_endline "PARENT_SIGINT"
  ```

  …and yet it is: pressing <kbd>Ctrl-C Ctrl-C</kbd> exits immediately.
- Maybe the signal is delivered to the main thread, which is waiting uninterruptibly in `Thread.join`.  If this was true, pressing <kbd>Ctrl-C Ctrl-C</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> would print `"PARENT_SIGINT"`.  But it doesn't: it prints `"CHILD_SIGINT"`, meaning that the signal was routed to the child thread and delayed until `input_line` completed. Surprisingly, though, this works (and it prints `CHILD_SIGINT`)

  ```
  let multithreaded_sigmask () =
    Sys.set_signal Sys.sigint (Sys.Signal_handle (fun _ -> raise SigInt));
    let go () =
      try 
        ignore (Thread.sigmask Unix.SIG_SETMASK []);
        output_string stdout (input_line stdin);
      with SigInt -> print_endline "CHILD_SIGINT" in
    try
      ignore (Thread.sigmask Unix.SIG_SETMASK [Sys.sigint]);
      Thread.join (Thread.create go ());
    with SigInt -> print_endline "PARENT_SIGINT"
  ```

  … but sigmask is not available on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Two things are working together to make the behavior hard to understand.  The first is OS signal delivery to the process.  The second is how the OCaml runtime delivers them to the application code.

Looking at the OCaml source code, its OS signal handler simply records the fact that a signal was raised, via a global variable.  That flag is then polled by other parts of the OCaml runtime, at times when it is safe to deliver the signal.  So the Thread.sigmask controls which thread(s) the OS signal can be delivered on, to the OCaml runtime.  It does not control delivery to your app.

Pending signals are delivered by caml_process_pending_signals(), which is called by caml_enter_blocking_section() and caml_leave_blocking_section().  There is no thread mask or affinity here... the first thread to process the global list of pending signals does so.

The input_line function polls the OS for fresh input, and each time it does, it enters and leaves the blocking section, so it is polling frequently for signals.

Thread.join enters the blocking section, then blocks indefinitely, until the thread is finished, then leaves the blocking section.  So while it is waiting, it is not polling for pending signals.

In your first interruptable example, what happens if you actually type and hit enter?  Does the input_line call actually accumulate input and return it?  It may not.. the Thread.join may own the blocking section and be preventing input and signal delivery process-wide.

Comment: Thanks, this is enlightening.  `input_line` works does work in the first multithreaded example.